# Make a payment through PayPal API in ASP.NET Core

Tags: ajax, authentication, asp.net-core, paypal, payment-gateway

I am doing a project in ASP.NET Core. My requirement is, I want to integrate PayPal  as the payment gateway.

User can see set of items, with **BUY NOW** button, and when a button is clicked, i want to send that item's name and cost to paypal so it will charge the amount from the user.

When the payment is successful, I want paypal to redirect to one of Controller method and save that transaction.

Now my problem is,

1. I am not sure if I am using the correct API.
2. Even though I use that API, I get an error with 400 code

I use below code to generate the token.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('client ID and secret'));
            },
            data: {
                'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            });
```

The above function is giving me a key and using that, i do the below API call. Now I am not sure if the below API is correct for this purpose.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            },
            data: {
                "intent": "sale",
                "payer": {
                    "payment_method": "paypal"
                },
                "transactions": [
                    {
                        "amount": {
                            "total": "30.11",
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "details": {
                                "subtotal": "30.00",
                                "tax": "0.07",
                                "shipping": "0.03",
                                "handling_fee": "1.00",
                                "shipping_discount": "-1.00",
                                "insurance": "0.01"
                            }
                        },
                        "description": "The payment transaction description.",
                        "custom": "EBAY_EMS_90048630024435",
                        "invoice_number": "48787589673",
                        "payment_options": {
                            "allowed_payment_method": "INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE"
                        },
                        "soft_descriptor": "ECHI5786786",
                        "item_list": {
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "name": "hat",
                                    "description": "Brown hat.",
                                    "quantity": "5",
                                    "price": "3",
                                    "tax": "0.01",
                                    "sku": "1",
                                    "currency": "USD"
                                }
                            ],
                            "shipping_address": {
                                "recipient_name": "Brian Robinson",
                                "line1": "4th Floor",
                                "line2": "Unit #34",
                                "city": "San Jose",
                                "country_code": "US",
                                "postal_code": "95131",
                                "phone": "011862212345678",
                                "state": "CA"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "note_to_payer": "Contact us for any questions on your order.",
                "redirect_urls": {
                    "return_url": "https://example.com/return",
                    "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel"
                }
```

**Above API call is the exact example in the PayPal developer's website** itself but however it gives me the following error:

```
{"name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error","rel":"information_link"}]}
```

Is this the correct API that I should use or is there any other? Please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you also post `btoa` function source code? And do you have valid sandbox auth key?

Comment: @Ignas Yes I do have both client id and a secret key, i send them both through the paypal API to get the access token generated. Also the btoa seems to be an inbuilt function in js, so i just used as it was mentioned in the paypal api docs

Comment: From the server response code it seems like your authentication part is wrong. Can you post the actual HTTP request with headers from e.g. Chrome Developer's Console? Or Fiddler.